# How do I delete a time series from Prometheus v2, specifically a series of alerts

Tags: prometheus

We are getting to grips with alerting so from time to time need to clear out old alerts which we did by calling the HTTP API, to remove the pseudo time series where the alerts were stored, e.g.:

```
DELETE https://prometheus/api/v1/series?match[]={__name__="ALERTS"}
```

We have recently upgraded our Prometheus server from 1.8 to 2.2.1.

Calling this endpoint now gives

```
{
    "status": "error",
    "errorType": "internal",
    "error": "not implemented"
}
```

I have done some research and found a solution in various locations, which I will summarise in an answer below in case it's of use to my fellow StackOverflowers

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Firstly the admin API is not enabled by default in Prometheus 2. This must be made active by starting the server with the option

```
--web.enable-admin-api
```

There is a new endpoint in v2 at

```
https://prometheus/api/v2/admin/tsdb/delete_series
```

This takes a `POST` specifying the search criteria, e.g. for a time series with the name `ALERTS` where the alert name is `MyTestAlert`, post the following `application/json` to the `delete_series` endpoint, from the tool of choice (Tested with Postman 6 on Mac)

```
{
    "matchers": [{
        "type": "EQ",
        "name": "__name__",
        "value": "ALERTS"
    },
    {
        "type": "EQ",
        "name": "alertname",
        "value": "MyTestAlert"
    }]
}
```

For completeness and to free the disk space where the alerts were persisted, `POST` an empty payload to

```
https://prometheus/api/v2/admin/tsdb/clean_tombstones
```

Answer aggregated from:

- https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/
- https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3584
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/prometheus-users/ToMKsb9fYp8/az6afuX3CgAJ

Comment: Using `curl` might be easier...  Robust Perception has an example, https://www.robustperception.io/deleting-time-series-from-prometheus

Comment: Cheers, that example didn't exist back in April. Don't see the advantage of curl over any other http posting utility though.

Comment: I get error response with "message": "unknown value \"EQ\" for enum prometheus.LabelMatcher_Type" and code 3

Comment: I deleted series and cleaned up tombstones, but I can still see the metric names in the drop-down in the Console page. There is no data for deleted metrics, but they are still there for some reason. Reload via webAPI, kill -HUP did not help. Anybody knows how to wipe the out?

Comment: Use `/api/v1/admin/tsdb/delete_series` and `/api/v1/admin/tsdb/clean_tombstones` (v1 instead of mentions v2). See https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#delete-series

Answer (score 5):

Curl variant:

```
# delete alerts series
curl -g -XPOST 'http://prometheus:9090/api/v1/admin/tsdb/delete_series?match[]=ALERTS'

# delete data from disk
curl -XPOST http://prometheus:9090/api/v1/admin/tsdb/clean_tombstones
```

Comment: recent versions seem to have changed the URLs to ```/v1/``` see here: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#delete-series